# How to know all items of a list-view has been viewed in android?

Tags: android, listview

I have created on list-view in android.
Here my need is to toast one message as "you have viewed all items in this list-view".

ie., after viewing of all items from the list-view,Automatically i need to show like the above message,how to do this?

suggestions please

Thanks for your precious time!..

**ListFruitActivity.java**

```
public class ListFruitActivity extends ListActivity {

static final String[] FRUITS = new String[] { "Apple", "Avocado", "Banana",
        "Blueberry", "Coconut", "Durian", "Guava", "Kiwifruit",
        "Jackfruit", "Mango", "Olive", "Pear", "Sugar-apple" };

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // no more this
    // setContentView(R.layout.list_fruit);

    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_fruit,FRUITS));

    ListView listView = getListView();
    listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            ((TextView) view).getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }); }}
```

Comment: In getView() of adapter it will return the position of last item of listview.

Comment: @Saurabh can u please show me one sample?

Comment: Create one Adapter class and extend it to BaseAdapter, it will have getView(int position, View v, ViewGroup parent)
In this function you will get the last position.
In short create one custom list view.

Comment: check your recent answer from amourreux, It will solve your problem.

Comment: I think, creating custom listview will be more suitable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> listView.getLastVisiblePosition()

Returns the position within the adapter's data set for the last item displayed on screen.

```
listview.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent arg1) {
            //needs to be optimized
            int count = ((ListView) v).getLastVisiblePosition();

            if(count == maxRow)
            {
                //make toast,
            }
            return false;
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple example of what you want can be done using a HashMap. Here is a quick sample

```
HashMap map = new HashMap();
map.put("Apple", false);
map.put("Avocado", false);
//same for the rest of your fruit
```

In the onItemClickListener you can set the value of the item in the map with the given key to true.

```
map.put("Apple", true);
```

At the same time you can check if you have any `false` values in the map, if not all your items have been viewed.

Another approach would be to add a custom object to your list and set a property (e.g `boolean viewed;`) and set it on true when you view the said list item.